# How to tell if a resource is null?

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to do a mysql_query - and I want to tell if a resource is null (that is, was unable to pull any values). Would the query be returned as false if no values were present? Am I reading the documentation right on this?

Answer (score 5):

You can count the number of returned rows with [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), and check how many were received from the query.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM...");
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0 ) {
    // Got some results
} else {
    //no rows
}
```

However note that if the query failed due to an invalid SQL or some other reason, `$results` will be false, so you can just do:

```
if(!$results) {
    // Query was invalid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) for this.

If `mysql_query()` returns `FALSE`it means there was an actaul problem with the query operation, not that there were no rows returned.

The flow goes something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wherever";
if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
  // mysql_error() gives a human readable string that explains what went wrong
  // You should **never** show it in a production environment!
  die('MySQL Error: '.mysql_error());
}

if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  // There were no results
} else {
  // There were some results
}
```

This is only true for queries that return data (`SELECT`, `DESCRIBE` etc) - queries that just perform an action (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc) will always return `TRUE` if the action was successful, or `FALSE` if it failed.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no records to return, `mysql_num_rows($resultHandle)` would return 0 (zero)

Answer (score 0):

No, `mysql_query` will return a resource (not `FALSE`) also if your `SELECT` query do not return any rows. To check if no rows have been returned, you can use a bounch of functions:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
>   ...

Answer (score -2):

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

To check if it's success, it might be a good idea to use `isset` or `!empty`:

```
$rs = mysql_query("select 1");
if (!empty($rs)){
    //everything ran fine
}
else{
    //something broken
}
```

Comment: That's not what the user wants.